# When do we use "arrive at" versus "arrive in"?

Tags: word-choice, differences, prepositions, at-in

When do we use "at" and "in" with "arrive" talking about place, not time?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

*Arrive* carries 3 prepositions: *in*, *on*, or *at*.

1. He arrived **in** New York.
2. He arrived **at** the station.
3. He arrived **on the scene of** the accident.

Also:

- He arrived here. [no preposition]
- He arrived **at** 12 o'clock.
- He arrived **within** 10 minutes.
- He will arrive **in** an hour.

So it turns out that '*arrive*' either carries or doesn't carry a preposition depending on the place or time that follows it, i.e. if the place or the time carries a preposition.

Comment: we don't usually say "in New York" or "at the station" when we say about the direction. We usually say "to New York" or "to the station". With ariive it's a different story! That's why it's confusing.

Comment: @Valentina: I guess the reason is that, once you've arrived, you've stopped moving - so it's no longer about a direction, it's just a place. At least - that might be a good way of remembering :)

Comment: Wow, that's an interesting idea! I've never thought of it, thank you! It's really a new explanation for me. But what's about if we want to say: "I've come to New York". I've also stopped moving! But it's still TO :)

Comment: The Oxford Advanced Learners' Dictionary states the example of 'arrive' with 'in' as: 'in New York'.

Comment: "I arrived *in* Stuttgart at midday": I think of *Stuttgart* as a town.    "I arrived *at* Stuttgart" at midday": I think of *Stuttgart* as a railway station or airport.

Answer (score 11):

For time:

'at' with a specific point in time = "I will arrive at 4:30"

'in' with a period of time = "I will arrive in 30mins"

Confusingly it's 'on' with a day = "I will arrive on tuesday"

For places:

'in' with general areas, countries, cities etc. = "I will arrive in Italy", "I will arrive in Rome"

'at' with specific places = "I will arrive at your house", "I will arrive at the airport"

You can use also use 'in' with a specific place if you mean specifically inside.
"I will meet you at the shop", could be waiting outside - but "I will meet you in the shop"  means I will be inside.

Comment: what's if we talk about a place?

Comment: You can also "_arrive in_ a car."

Comment: what does it mean - arrive IN a car??? Is it the same as BY car?

Comment: @Valentina, in a car, by car mean the same thing generally

Answer (score 0):

AT and IN
It is taught that IN is used before the names of big places like towns, cities, states, and countries and that AT before the names of small places like villages. I live in the District of Kannur, in Kerala State of India. I will say: I live in Kannur|I live in Kerala|I live in India. The locality I live in is known as Naluvayal. It is a small place. A friend of mine who does not live there will say: Abootty lives AT Naluvayal. It is because he does not give any importance to Naluvayal. At the same time for me Naluvayal is an important place since my house is there. So I will say: I live IN Naluvayal.