# Flight arrived "in" or "at"?

Tags: prepositions, at-in

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [When do we use “arrive at” versus “arrive in”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/20768/when-do-we-use-arrive-at-versus-arrive-in)

Is the usage **at** or **in** correct in following sentences?

> a. Flight has arrived ***in*** Tokyo.
>
> b. Flight has arrived ***at*** Tokyo airport.

Comment: Well, you have two different cases there--one is a city, one is an airport. Did you mean to ask only about one?

Comment: i want to know whether in/on usage is correct in two situations?

Comment: If you have two situations, you have two questions

Answer (score 4):

Both of your sentences are correct. American English speakers, and Brits as far a I know, would say "in" a city and "at" an airport. The word "in" is a little less precise than "at", and so fits better with the generalized city vs the more specific location of the airport.

Answer (score 3):

We normally use "arrive in" for cities, towns, and countries, and "arrive at" for other places. So both your sentences are correct and:

1. arrive **at** the airport
2. arrive **at** Tokyo Airport
3. arrive **in** Tokyo

But if you're referring to a *point on a journey*, this also becomes possible:

1. arrive **at** Tokyo

P.S. "Flight" is a Countable Noun so you need either an Article or a Possessive Pronoun to go with it

Answer (score 2):

You need an article before "flight".
You need an indefinite article before "Tokyo airport" because there is Narita airport and Haneda airport in Tokyo.
While "... arrived at a Tokyo airport" does not sound natural to me, the grammar is correct in both.

Answer (score 1):

Both of your suggested phrases sound good to me. I don't think that the opposites work ("at Tokyo" and "in Tokyo airport").

Comment: If someone said "in Tokyo airport" I'd think they meant "inside Tokyo airport", so I'd agree with JAM.