# "In a restaurant" or "at a restaurant"

Tags: differences, prepositions

Does anyone know if one should use "in a restaurant" or "at a restaurant" ?

Ex: Having a romantic dinner in a restaurant or having a romantic dinner at a restaurant.

What is the difference between the two ?

Comment: why the downvote?

Comment: We have many, many at-in questions here. [Difference between at and in when specifying location](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/87306/difference-between-at-and-in-when-specifying-location) is probably the most comprehensive, but you can use `[at-in]` to search for more answers.