# Preposition arrived "at" or "in"

Tags: prepositions

Mr. Dursley arrived in the Grunnings parking lot. We use "at" for a specific place. So why "in" used in this sentence?

Comment: Check [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=arrived+at+in) page for your answer.

Comment: To be extra specific, [here's a thread](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/20768/when-do-we-use-arrive-at-versus-arrive-in) that should satisfactorily answer your question once and for all.