# Sunrise in or sunrise at somewhere

Tags: prepositions

I have a doubt and I do not know which preposition should I use. I have been looking for this a few days and I do not find any explanation about it.

Should I say 'Sunrise in Bondi beach' or 'Sunrise at Bondi beach'? And why?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When do we use "arrive at" versus "arrive in"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/20768/when-do-we-use-arrive-at-versus-arrive-in)

Comment: Are you talking about being there at a certain time of day or are you talking about watching the process and, possibly, writing the caption for a photograph. If it's the latter then "sunrise over" may be more appropriate than either 'at' or 'in'.

Comment: Note also that "beach" is part of the name of the location and should therefore be capitalised: [Bondi Beach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bondi_Beach).

Comment: @BoldBen I meant being there watching the process.

Comment: You can't have a Sunrise in a beach, that would mean inside of the beach.  It has to be at a beach.  "At" means located there. In this case, the sunrise occurred there.

Comment: In that case I'd probably use either "at" or "over". If you were talking about Long Beach in California you might use "in" but only because Long Beach is a city. If you were talking about watching from the actual _beach_ at Long Beach then it 's either "at" or "over".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sunrise at Bondi, **at** implies a very specific spot.

Sunrise in NSW, **in** seems to imply a wider area and not a specific location.

That's how I use it; I realize that there is flexibility in how broad an area or how distinct a location can be for either use depending on the context.